# Use button to enable timer inside a function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm making something in actionscript 3, and when I press the first button `btnSkaffPenger`, it increases the number by 1 for each click. But my second button `btnTrePrinter` is supposed to increase the number by 1 every 2 seconds, automatically, but only works once, and doesnt reset. (I added so you can only press the button once, I don't think that interferes with the function resetting)

Thanks

The buttons code:

```
btnTrePrinter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trePrinter);
function trePrinter(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    var harVentet:Function = function(event:TimerEvent):void{
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
        timer = null;

        sumPenger++
        txtSumPenger.text = sumPenger.toString();
    }
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
    timer.start();

    btnTrePrinter.mouseEnabled = false;
    btnTrePrinter.alpha=0.4;
}
```

Full code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var sumPenger:int = 0;

btnSkaffPenger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, penger1);
function penger1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    sumPenger++
    txtSumPenger.text = sumPenger.toString();
}

btnTrePrinter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trePrinter);
function trePrinter(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    var harVentet:Function = function(event:TimerEvent):void{
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
        timer = null;

        sumPenger++
        txtSumPenger.text = sumPenger.toString();
    }
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
    timer.start();

    btnTrePrinter.mouseEnabled = false;
    btnTrePrinter.alpha=0.4;
}
```

Comment: If you want this timer to change the value each two seconds, why do you kill the timer after the first function call? Remove this code: `timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
        timer = null;` and the timer will work as you expect.

Comment: wow thanks, feel stupid now.
Thank you so much, I seriously wouldn't have found out! <3

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped!

Comment: @Nbooo please do not post answers as comments. Post your comment as an answer so that Evan can accept it. (and people can upvote it ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was told, it's a bad practice to put the answer in comments, so I post it once again.

Just to clarify what happens in your code:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
// the timer created with 2 seconds delay and infinite repeats 

var harVentet:Function = function(event:TimerEvent):void {
    // 2 seconds passed after "timer.start()" call
    // it's the first invocation of this listener
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
    timer = null;
    // the listener is removed and timer is destroyed
    // since the listener removed from timer, no more invocations will happen
    sumPenger++
    txtSumPenger.text = sumPenger.toString();
}
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
// the listener is added to timer
timer.start();
// the timer starts
```

Remove this code:

```
timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, harVentet);
timer = null;
```

and the timer will work as you expect.